# Passing session variable data from jsp to java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, session-variables

I have created session variables since I want to transfer data from one JSP to another.
Each of my JSPs is a tab.
I transfer data given from the user from one JSP to another using the request body. I have `<form>..><button type = "submit"/> </form>` in the last JSP from where I submit the data and use it in a Java class.

When I try to access the session data from all the JSP pages, it returns a null value for all the data.

How should I transfer all the session data from all the JSPs to a Java class?
Please note that each JSP is a tab, and I submit data from the last JSP.

Code:

```
<% 
    String joindate = request.getParameter( "joindate" );
    session.setAttribute("joindate",joindate);
    String birthdate = request.getParameter( "birthdate" );
    session.setAttribute("birthdate",birthdate);
%>
```

Comment: How do you set the session variable ? how do you try to read it ? without posting some code it's difficult to understand the source of the  problem

Comment: show the code in jsp which is setting the value in session pls

Comment: <%
String joindate = request.getParameter( "joindate" );
   session.setAttribute( "joindate",joindate);
   
   String birthdate = request.getParameter( "birthdate" );
   session.setAttribute( "birthdate",birthdate);
   
%>

This is a sample code of how I set session variables. I mean this is how I had done. Is it right?

Comment: And how is session variable set here? Did you use HttpSession session = request.getSession() or a servletcontext implementation?

Comment: No I havent used the above what u suggested. How do I do that?

Comment: No I havent used it. How do I do that?
I have only used the above code and it displays the data when I try to print it to see if i get the data

Comment: In your class, try doing this, 'request.getSession().getAttribute("joindate");'

Comment: You mean in the java class right?
I have used String joindate = areq.getParameter("joindate"); in my java class and when I was trying to print the value it showed me null.

Comment: What does "tab" mean in this context?  Why would you not use a controller (MVC style) to pull data from the JSP instead?

Comment: it is a tabbed wizard. i have used different tabs for user to input different kind of data. ex. biodata,sports,hobbies. i have made tabs for each. like i said each tab is a jsp page

Comment: Makoto:
How do I use the controller class? I am not aware of it

Comment: Why are you still using scriptlets?

Comment: How should I go about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In general, just try to avoid scriptlets. You should definitely do what Makoto recommended: use a MVC pattern by having your JSPs submit their data to a servlet, which does the heavy duty lifting.

Whenever you have a form in a JSP, consider using

`<form action="servletpattern?action=add_date" method="post">`

Then in the servlet:

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 String action = request.getParameter("action");
 if(action.equals("add_date")){
     String joindate = request.getParameter( "joindate" );
     session.setAttribute("joindate",joindate);
     String birthdate = request.getParameter( "birthdate" );
     session.setAttribute("birthdate",birthdate);
 } else if(action.equals("someotheraction"){
     //do something else
 }
```

In the JSP you should again not use scriptlets but instead access the session variables through EL :

```
join date: ${joindate}, birth date: ${birthdate}
```

Comment: zz3599 : Thanks a lot. I will try this out. in my java class where I am trying to access the variables I am extending MVCPortlet class . Now for using session I will need to extend HttpSession class too right?
But java doesn't support multiple inheritance. so how do i go about this? create another separate java class?
I haven't worked with servlets so I am getting confused

Comment: Is it possible to get the variable values without using httpsession?
what i mean is is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean? You are getting the variables from the request, and then setting in them in the session. If you want your variables to persist across multiple JSP's (in your case) then you want to set it in the session.

Comment: Yes thats right. so i think i will have to use the approach that u suggested. but i need to extend mvcportlet class and if now that m using session i need to use httpsession class. how do i extend both these classes as java doesnt support multiple inheritance? m confused now

Comment: No, you do not need to extend httpsession class. Just import javax.servlet.http.Httpsession

Comment: zz3599 : hey i know this is a silly question. 
import javax.servlet.http.Httpsession cannot be resolved to a type. do i need to import any jar?

Comment: zz3599: hey it is resolved. i will try ur example n let u know here

Comment: i imported import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; in my java class
my function is like : 
public void addEmployeeData(HttpServletRequest areq, HttpServletResponse aRes)  throws Exception,ServletException{
......
}

but wen i run the code i get the error saying NewPortlet.addEmployeeData(ActionRequest areq,ActionResponse ares) cannot be found. earlier i was using this actionreq and actionresponse but now i changed it. y do i still get this error?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using portlets instead of servlets?

Comment: I am developing a portlet application. NewPortlet is the name i have given to java class